# Docker pulls image of wrong architecture for M1

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, apple-m1

I am trying to run custom image above [this image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/rabbitmq/3.11.7-management/images/sha256-8debda917024653ed181814fcf4df3409d2f210b32495b83092431a3130a3b5d?context=explore)

This image should support arm architecture. Running the current state of custom image above on MacBook Pro M1 Max (Which uses ARM internally) causes error `qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped` and after while of googling, I´ve found that this issue is probably caused by image is not compiled for `linux/arm64` architecture.

So I´ve managed to build image with `buildx` for `linux/arm64` and `linux/amd64` for my current sandbox repository in Docker Hub and everything looks allright.

[image]

**But when I want to use this image inside my docker-compose**, I am getting the same error. I should mention that there is no additional modifier of architecture in the docker compose

```
  my-service:
    image: my-docker-hub/my-image:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ... omitted for simplicity
```

If I inspect image with `docker image inspect` **I see only one architecture and that is amd64, not arm64**

```
... omitted for simplicity
"Architecture": "amd64",
"Os": "linux",
... omitted for simplicity
```

Is there any way how to tell docker to pull arm images if present? I thought Docker should be clever enough to do this on his own. I would not like to modify docker-compose with addict arm architecture at all cause it is being used by other developers and its used on linux amd servers as well. And I would like to avoid duplicating this compose to amd/arm versions.

I would like to work it out of the box.

EDIT:

Result of docker `buildx imagetools inspect johnczek/sandbox:latest`

> Name:      docker.io/johnczek/sandbox:latest MediaType:
> application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json Digest:
> sha256:3a9513161f3d9ca3a20da37b921fb682fd3481710b9457d84c67bc0907e3864c
>
> Manifests:   Name:
> docker.io/johnczek/sandbox:latest@sha256:cdd7729d9b4aa3550edc1d15d6b74dd26f1cf56cfc5c798f578a6bce58682569
> MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json   Platform:
> linux/amd64
>
> Name:
> docker.io/johnczek/sandbox:latest@sha256:4738d2c8d60fe306fffe76b83d33414442c4d49ad4d0777f3c8f58bb16ebdeb8
> MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json   Platform:
> linux/arm64
>
> Name:
> docker.io/johnczek/sandbox:latest@sha256:ba4101895734fe3c7285066f351cd65264d0f70f3e305a7f7edbd3a122c99a83
> MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json   Platform:
> unknown/unknown   Annotations:
> vnd.docker.reference.digest: sha256:cdd7729d9b4aa3550edc1d15d6b74dd26f1cf56cfc5c798f578a6bce58682569
> vnd.docker.reference.type:   attestation-manifest
>
> Name:
> docker.io/johnczek/sandbox:latest@sha256:091f9094c09e6bbbed985f8eceb9912e94eb3758e22fe582a76d26f84ec61e50
> MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json   Platform:
> unknown/unknown   Annotations:
> vnd.docker.reference.digest: sha256:4738d2c8d60fe306fffe76b83d33414442c4d49ad4d0777f3c8f58bb16ebdeb8
> vnd.docker.reference.type:   attestation-manifest

Comment: What does `docker buildx imagetools inspect johnczek/sandbox:latest` give you?

Comment: @GlenYu Thats for reply, I´ve added response in my question